# about py2exe and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, py2exe, importerror

morning everyboby,I met some problems when I was using py2exe to packet some .py documents. As far as I know, the problem was corresponding to the 'matplotlib' lib because I could packet the procedure successfully before I use the 'matplotlib'. Here is the error tips when I start the 'main.exe'.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

# Remove the build folder, a bit slower but ensures that build contains the latest
import shutil
shutil.rmtree("build", ignore_errors=True)

# my setup.py is based on one generated with gui2exe, so data_files is done a bit differently
data_files = []
includes = ["sip","matplotlib.backends","matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg",
                                        "matplotlib.figure","pylab", "numpy",
                                        "matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg"]
excludes = ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'pywin.debugger',
            'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl',
            'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter', 'pydoc', 'doctest', 'test', 'sqlite3'
            ]
packages = ['matplotlib','pytz']
dll_excludes = ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 'tcl84.dll',
                'tk84.dll','libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll']
icon_resources = []
bitmap_resources = []
other_resources = []

# add the mpl mpl-data folder and rc file
import matplotlib as mpl
data_files += mpl.get_py2exe_datafiles()

setup(
    console=["main.py","debug.py"],
                          # compressed and optimize reduce the size
    options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 2, 
                          "optimize": 2,
                          "includes": includes,
                          "excludes": excludes,
                          "packages": packages,
                          "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
                          # using 2 to reduce number of files in dist folder
                          # using 1 is not recommended as it often does not work
                          "bundle_files": 2,
                          "dist_dir": 'dist',
                          "custom_boot_script": '',
                         }
              },

    # using zipfile to reduce number of files in dist
    zipfile = r'lib\library.zip',

    data_files=data_files
)
```

error tips:
ImportError: cannot import name stats

Thanks~

Comment: Have you tried adding the full `matplotlib` to your includes, instead of just the backends and figure?

Comment: I just tried as what you said, but still the same mistake...

Comment: Where do you use/import `stats` (as in the error)? Is that an external package or one that you've built yourself?

Comment: I have solved the problem in another way, but still thank you!

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer for other people that come across this question

Comment: In fact,I just changed a computer and it worked...The codes are correct.